# Non-technical: Can an existing customer be a lead?

Tags: opportunity, leads, lead-conversion

This question is non-technical. It's more based on the principles of CRM and how SalesForce implements those principles:

When talking about new customers and the sales funnel it's quite clear:

Lead -> Opportunity -> Customer/Account

Let's assume I want to sell a new product (Product B) to an existing customer (who already bought Product A) (not cross selling nor upgrade)? Will, from a product view, the existing customer be a lead again? Or an opportunity?

Comment: You can consider it as a Opportunity or more specific Opportunity as upsell  or opportunity with downsell

Comment: If using a marketing automation system like Eloqua, Marketo, Hubspot, ... you may find that the existing customer is touched on some marketing channel and upon response, becomes a Lead object in SFDC on the next marketing automation sync.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it would be considered a new Opportunity for an existing customer, but it could also be a Lead if, for example, the data is coming from an external system, and the customer has not been matched up with the existing customer in your org.  In that scenario it would be considered a Lead.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is 'yes' because all businesses are unique and surely there are some businesses where an existing customer could also be a lead.

Answer (score 0):

Its an opportunity 
you can create an opportunity for that existing customer which is an Account for your ORG.